# ModalBox Email pass php variable to sms sender

Tags: php, jquery, email, variables, post

Ok, so I use ModalBox to create an email form on my website..however, i need the modal box to send the email not to me, but to the user who added the car(its a car selling website), and so I need to pass the $email variable to the sendmessage.php.

This is what i did so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


    $("#send").on("click", function(){
    setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 10);
        var emailval  = $("#email").val();
        var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
        var msglen    = msgval.length;
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

        if(mailvalid == false) {
            $("#email").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(mailvalid == true){
            $("#email").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(msglen < 4) {
            $("#msg").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(msglen >= 4){
            $("#msg").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
            // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
            // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
            $("#send").replaceWith("<em>Se trimite...</em>");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://automoka.ro/sendmessage.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong>Mesajul a fost trimis!</strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 10);
                            $_POST['contact'] = $email;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and in the php sender :

```
$email = $_POST['contact'];

$sendto   = $email;
$usermail = $_POST['email'];
$content  = nl2br($_POST['msg']);

if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help....Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:
Nevermind..figured it out!...I added another textarea which was hidden to the modalbox...and used post to get it to sendmessage.php.**